# Opengl Lighting Artifact (calculating light before translation)

Tags: opengl, lighting, artifact

I am trying to create a scene in opengl and I am having trouble with my lighting. I believe it is something to do with translating my models from the origin of the world into their respective places.

I only have 1 light in my scene placed on the right in the centre of the world, however you can see the light on the wall at the front of the scene.

I have wrote my own shaders. I suspect that I'm calculating the lighting too early as it seems that it is being calculated before the models are being translated around the world, that or I am using local coordinates rather than world coordinates (I think thats right anyway...).

(please ignore the glass, they are using a global light and a different shader)

[image: Light in scene]

Does anyone know if this is indeed the case or where would be the best place to find a solution.

Below is how I call rendering my models.

```
glUseProgram(modelShader);

//center floor mat 
if (floorMat)
{
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelShader_modelMatrixLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, (GLfloat*)&(modelTransform.M));
    floorMat->setTextureForModel(carpetTexture);
    floorMat->renderTexturedModel();
}
```

Comment: I find this to be a great website for both learning as well as a good reference to modern OpenGL. https://learnopengl.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_1430411783&feature=iv&index=86&list=PLRwVmtr-pp06qT6ckboaOhnm9FxmzHpbY&src_vid=NH68sIdF-48&v=P3DQXzyjswQ

Turns out I was not calculating the lighting in world space.

Rather than using the transposed modelworldposition I was just using the plain vertex position

Comment: Otherwise consider adding this information by Editing your Question.